# Why is JSON object undefined in Node-Express app

Tags: xml, express, httprequest

I'm using Node and express. Currently trying to test out sending httprequests to the server using AJAX. Whilst everything seems to work fine client-side, with the JSON in the request payload, as expected, the object appears 'undefined' by the time it hits my server-side code. I've spent so long trying to figure this out, and would greatly appreciate any help with this.

Client-side JS:

```
   var testOb = {
    name: "me", 
    age: 30, 
    lives: "Ireland"}                        }

    var jsontest = JSON.stringify(testOb);

function xhtmR () {

let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open('POST', '/word-request', true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
xmlhttp.send(jsontest);
}
```

Server side:

```
 let express = require('express');
 let app = express();
 let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 app.use(express.static('assets'));
 let request = require('request');
 app.use(bodyParser.json());

 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({useNewUrlParser: true}));

 app.post('/word-request', (req, res) => {
 console.log('request received for ')
 console.log(req.body.jsontest)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

‍ You have to call this function: `xHtmR` to call your backend. It's looks like this code below:

```js
var testOb = {
  name: "me", 
  age: 30, 
  lives: "Ireland"}                        

  var jsontest = JSON.stringify(testOb);

function xhtmR () {

let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.open('POST', 'http://localhost:3000/word-request', true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
xmlhttp.send(jsontest);
}

// call this function for send post to backend
// or you can add this function in your button click: on-click maybe.
xhtmR();
```

**And now**, you can change your `server` with this code below:

```js
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(express.static('assets'));

app.use(cors({ origin: '*'}))

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({useNewUrlParser: true}));

app.post('/word-request', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is up');
})
```

**After that**, don't forget to `run` your server and then, you can load your html page, where the javascript client-side you load .

> I've been try the code above, and it's working fine.

I hope it's can help you .